# Trying to display bitmap in fullscreen ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, size

I am trying to display an image in a full screen ImageView.  I keep getting an exception for dividing by zero.  How can I get the ImageView width and height so that I can scale my image?

If I hardcode the dimensions everything works as expected.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SingleImageActivity extends Activity{
    private ImageView mFullPageImage;
    private static final String SELECTED_FILEPATH = "msd.com.example.dailyselfie.selected_filepath";
    private String filepath;
    int targetW;
    int targetH;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_image_activity);

        mFullPageImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullPageImageView);


        filepath = getIntent().getExtras().getString(SELECTED_FILEPATH);

        processPicture(filepath);

        //Toast.makeText(this, filename, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    }

    @Override
     public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
         targetW = mFullPageImage.getWidth();
         targetH = mFullPageImage.getHeight();


     }

    protected void processPicture(String filepath){
        //targetW = mFullPageImage.getWidth();
        //targetH = mFullPageImage.getHeight();
        //targetW = 400;
        //targetH = 400;


        // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, bmOptions);
        int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
        int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

        // Determine how much to scale down the image
        int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

        // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, bmOptions);
        //display with no options
        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
        mFullPageImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set bitmap in full screen, you can use below code to get width and height of screen.

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width=size.x;
    int height= size.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `divide by zero exception` because values of `targetW` and `targetH` are zero. And in this line you are trying to divide a value by zero

`int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);`

If you call `getHeight` or `getWidth` method on any view before  android completes drawing it on the screen it will return zero.

So please listen to the completion of drawing of the view using `ViewTreeObserver`

And one more thing I wanted ask is are you trying maintain aspect ratio of the image or you are ok with if image get stretched.